# Remove parent key from object in array of other objects with no parent key

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I am fetching data from different sources and have ended up with a several correctly formed json objects and one which has parent keys like below:

```
{
"0": {
      "term_id": 3,
      "name": "Burger"
     },
"1": {
      "term_id": 6,
      "name": "Chicken"
     },
"2": {
      "term_id": 12,
      "name": "Mexican"
     },
}
```

How can I remove 0, 1, 2, 3 etc while also preserving other correctly structured objects? I am using lodash elsewhere in this project

This object with parent keys is being inserted into an array of multiple objects via a map

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    let valueArr = [];
    Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
      valueArr = [results[key]]
    });
    this.setState({ categorySelectOptions: valueArr });
  })
```

This is a screenshot of the output with the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.values`

```js
const data = {
  "0": {
    "term_id": 3,
    "name": "Burger"
  },
  "1": {
    "term_id": 6,
    "name": "Chicken"
  },
  "2": {
    "term_id": 12,
    "name": "Mexican"
  },
};

console.log(Object.values(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is `push` into the array instead of `assigning`. Use this -

```
Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
  valueArr.push(results[key])
});
```

Comment: It still pushes the object with the parent keys as in the screenshot above. Thanks